# How can I center the menu? CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

How can I center the menu? And also I want the color changes when mouse comes on the menu buttons? Thanks for any help.

```
 div.menu {
    list-style:none;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    width:100% }
 div.menu ul{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;}
    div.menu li{
    display:inline; }
 div.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100px;
    background:#FBB117;
    color:#4C4646;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #fff; }

 div.menu lia:hover{
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000 }
```

I was working fine but I changed something and it is not at the center anymore. A bit left side. I cannot find what is wrong. Could you please help?

```
 div.menu {
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;} 
div.menu ul{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;}
 div.menu li{
    display:inline;}
 div.menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100px;
    background:#FBB117;
    color:#4C4646;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #fff; }
 div.menu li a:hover{
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like in [this sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c86dZ/).

1. Center the menu with `text-align:center` on the div, and `display:inline-block` on the list, and move the 20px margin from the div to the list.
2. To change colors on hover: add a space between `li` and `a`.

Comment: If it helped you, consider accepting this answer ([read how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)) to indicate that this question is handled.

Answer (score 0):

float the menu with auto margins.

use an onmouseover event to change the color on the buttons.

Comment: I used float in div.menu li a but doesnt work. which part of the code should I use float?

Answer (score 0):

to center any div you have to work with position absolue and relative, or specify the width in px, em, or inch, and after that use another div and use %.  Can you be more specific???

Comment: the menu is at the left side. Could you please show it to me on my code?

Answer (score 0):

I've got some CSS I knocked together a year or so ago that I call into play on pretty much every project I work on... feel free to use it. To use it all you need to do is style your list like this:

```
<ul id="mylist" class="linearlist center"><li>Link or something</li></ul>
```

This will allow you to centre align your menu really easily without using floats and having the collapsing container issue to deal with. You have a few options with styling classes - center, left, right, separators, inners, outers. Have a play around. Just make sure (a) you give it a class "linearlist" and make sure there is no whitespace in the HTML is some browsers render this.

```
/*************************************
FLAT LIST LAYOUT

    This can be called into use using the following classes:

            required        : linearlist
            select either   : centre / left / right
            optional        : separators
            outers / inners : adds or removes outermost borders

    Example usage:

            eg 1:  <ul class="linearlist right separators">
            eg 2:  <ul class="linearlist centre separators">
            eg 3:  <ul class="linearlist left">

    Support:
            IE6 :   :first-child and :last-child pseudoclasses are not supported
                    .inners and .outers will not work
            IE7 :   :last-child pseudoclass is not supported
                    .outers will not work but .inners will
            Note browser-sniffing is required to make list items full height in IE6 and IE7

    Remember - you will need to remove whitespace between list items for true rendering.

*************************************/
ul.linearlist, .linearlist ul          {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
ul.linearlist li,.linearlist ul li     {display: inline-block; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
*ul.linearlist li,*.linearlist ul li   {display: inline !important;}
ul.linearlist li a,.linearlist ul li a {display: inline-block;}

ul.separators li,.separators ul li                         {border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid;}
ul.inners li:first-child,.inners ul li:first-child {border-left-width: 0;} /* removes border from left-most list item  */
ul.outers,.outers ul {border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid;} /* adds border to right-most list item  */

ul.centre,ul.center,.centre ul,.center ul {text-align: center;}
ul.left,.left ul                          {text-align: left;}
ul.right,.right ul                        {text-align: right;}
```

Oh yeah, and you've got a little typo in your CSS that will be preventing the colour change on mouseover... your last declaration should be

```
div.menu li a:hover{
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000 }
```

However you could streamline it a little as it's bad practice to nest so many selectors... try this instead:

```
.menu a:hover{
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7zk8E/

You center the menu, by applying text-align:center to the outer div (you called its class menu).  I also changed the `.menu ul` display property to inline block, as inline elements don't get any padding or margin.

The reason your hover didn't work is because your CSS has a typo with `div.menu lia:hover`

it should be `div.menu li a:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for three links (33.3% width): [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u5y8w/)

```
.menu {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.menu ul {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
    width:33.3%; 
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#FBB117;
    color:#4C4646;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #fff; 
}

.menu a:hover {
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000; 
}
```

- You do not need to use the 'div' selector before any of these styles, so I took them out.
- div.menu **lia**:hover had a typo, is should have been **li a**:hover{}